# Does Hibernate/JPA CriteriaQuery trim function generate the wrong SQL for PostgreSQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, jpa-2.1

I'm trying to use the Criteria Query `trim()` function to strip the leading zero's of a field in the database. The relevant part of the criteria query is:

```
final Expression<String> _code = cmm.get(CodeMasterMapping_.code);
builder.equal(builder.trim(Trimspec.LEADING, Character.valueOf('0'), _code), productCode)));
```

The SQL generated by this snippet is:

```
trim(LEADING 0 from codemaster3_.comm_code)=?)
```

This leads to the following exception from Postgres:

> PSQLException: ERROR: function pg_catalog.ltrim(character varying, integer) does not exist
>   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I then changed the zero `0` to a character, thinking that maybe postgres is interpreting the zero `0` as an integer, hence triggering the exception.

Changing the character to be removed to an `A`:

```
builder.equal(builder.trim(Trimspec.LEADING, Character.valueOf('A'), _code), productCode)));
```

but that generates this SQL:

```
trim(LEADING A from codemaster3_.comm_code)=?)
```

and the following SQL exception:

> PSQLException: ERROR: column "a" does not exist

I have tested this on the following combinations with the exact same results

- Postgres 9.5.5, Wildfly 9.0.2.Final & Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
- Postgres 9.5.5, Wildfly 10.1.0.Final & Hibernate Core {5.0.10.Final}

Please let me know if you need more code for the Criteria Query.

According to the Postgres docs for [9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html) the `trim` function take these parameters:

```
trim([leading | trailing | both] [characters] from string)
```

and the given example is:

```
trim(both 'x' from 'xTomxx') --> 'Tom'
```

Is there something wrong with my use of the `CriteriaBuilder.trim()` function or should Hibernate generate SQL that use single quotes for trim character?

Comment: I don't really know Hibernate, but why don't you pass a `String` for the character to be removed? e.g. `"A"` instead of `Character.valueOf('A')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the trim() doesn't allow it -> `Expression<String> trim(Trimspec ts, Expression<Character> t, Expression<String> x);` `t` is `@param t  expression for character to be trimmed`

Comment: Hmm, doesn't really make sense as Postgres accepts a string with more then one character.

Comment: Confirmed as a bug - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11393

Comment: Bug fixed in Hibernate ORM 5.2.7.Final - Thank you @vlad-mihalcea